# Firebug multiple lines in console not working properly

Tags: javascript, console, firebug

Firebug doesn't show all lines in console. If my code looks like this:

```
var  arr=[4,3,2];

console.log("console");
arr;
```

result is in two lines as it should be:

```
console
[4, 3, 2]
```

but when it's a different order, only one line is shown at the end:

```
arr;
console.log("console");
```

result:

```
console
```

Problem appears with everything, and only using console, you can receive additional output line if it's put before array/object/function invokation, otherwise other outputs are skipped.
**Is there a way to make firebug produce input=>output result in console without actually skipping anything ?? If it's not possible, is there a different tool(with js compiler) that could do that ??**

Comment: You only get the _last evaluated value_ printed. In your second example, that is the log statement (which prints and is also evaluated to `undefined`). Why would you expect every single line in a multi-line script to produce output? If you really want to output something, then use the system you already know of `console.log(arr)`. It's not like doing `arr;` by itself actually does anything.

Comment: @vlaz Yes, but if a tool can print single line, than it could remember multiple lines and print them one after another. At least that kind of feature would be possible to achieve. I would like it to help with debbuging purposes, without need to add `console.log` to every array, function return, etc.

Comment: However, you can run an 100 line function code in the console. Do you _really_ want to see the output of every single one of them? Imagine there are loops, too. You could easily reach a 1000 or even more lines of output even from relatively simple code. Also worth noting that since this is IO it could _change how the code behaves_ as each line will need to wait to be printed, which may make your code run slower, which may, in turn, cause some unintended side-effects in some circumstances.

Comment: @vlaz No, but 100 lines of function code doesn't necessarily mean creating that much of an output. It would be nice to get an output of a few variables at given point of time, not only the last one at the end.

Comment: No, 100 lines of code should definitely produce 100 lines of output. At least. You said it yourself, you wanted _each_ line to be evaluated and printed. Each line of code will therefore print one thing in the console. But that's besides the point, if you really want few variables, then just do `console.log(a, b, c)` and you will get all three printed. If you want to get each line, then run your code normally and step through it with the debugger assigning watches and evaluating things on the fly. There is no reason to have the behaviour you want as it's worse than either of these options.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug and other browser developer tools output the return value of the evaluated script. Because there can only be one return value, you only get one output.

If you want to get more outputs, you need to use the [Console API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) methods like `console.log()`.

Instead of using the console for debugging your code, you may want to use the JavaScript debugger instead. In Firebug the debugger is available within the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel).
This allows you to stop the script execution at some line and see the values of all variables at that specific point of your code.

Comment: Debugging makes no help, since it allows to debug only script files on sites. I was aiming to write fast live scripts, mainly to excercise. Too bad that there is no tool that can save some time on checking values and stuff.

Comment: As said before, the way to output something to the console is to use the Console API. Just write `console.log(arr);` instead of `arr;` as @vlaz said.