# What does the last line of console output in Firefox DevTools mean?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, console, firefox-developer-tools

While testing a simple JavaScript `while` loop in the Firefox DevTools' console, I noticed that the last line of the output is different than in other consoles. Is this a bug in those tools? Can I change this e.g. in the settings manually?

Example:

[image: Firefox DevTools console output]

Comment: Why not give it a test in Chrome and see if the same thing happens. If it doesn't, it's probably a bug.

Comment: The reason is that the last time isn't returned by your loop. When you type that line into the console, it returns the value of ster AFTER all processing is done. That is a string, so it returns it in a string format (surrounded by quotes) rather than in a styled format.

Comment: I found that firebug by default shows the value of the last statement. So the last concatenation isn't logged in the console by the code, but by firebug (Like @Snowmonkey said, i guess). Similar behavior found by testing other loops. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Note that your screenshot is showing the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) with Firebug theme, not the Firebug extension. See the [related Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of the output is the value returned from the executed script, as I described in the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39735597/432681).

This return value is shown in all developer tools:

**Firebug**

[image: Return value of evaluated script in Firebug]

**Firefox DevTools**

[image: Return value of evaluated script in Firefox DevTools]

**Chrome DevTools**

[image: Return value of evaluated script in Chrome DevTools]

**Edge DevTools**

[image: Return value of evaluated script in Edge DevTools]